# Migrating bcrypt password hashes from a Laravel App to an Elixir app using Comeonin

Tags: laravel, hash, elixir, phoenix-framework, bcrypt

I'm in the process of replatforming a Laravel 5 app to Elixir Phoenix and want to assess the feasibility of migrating user accounts with their passwords. The laravel app uses the default Bcrypt password hashing and an example hash looks like this:

```
Hash::make("secret");
> $2y$10$gLbeMfXDRnQc9VHxuVAhke3yd4L69LQBeTqBOjw6TqQNca1nrW5E2
```

I'm using the [Comeonin](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin) library for the Phoenix app which produces a hash like this:

```
iex(2)> Comeonin.Bcrypt.hashpwsalt("secret")
"$2b$12$yecF6WXv0hIlyTxe5bLz..ghASJRFafObDrPUVEj3UarDflvfflq6"
```

When I try and check a hash generated by Laravel using Comeonin it fails:

```
iex(2)> Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw("secret","$2y$10$gLbeMfXDRnQc9VHxuVAhke3yd4L69LQBeTqBOjw6TqQNca1nrW5E2")
false
```

Why is this? Are there different implementations of Bcrypt? I can see the 2 hashes use a different number of rounds and variant (`2b` vs `2y`) but I would assume the library can read this from the prefixes in the hash.

Would it be possible to migrate these hashes without getting users to reset their passwords?

Comment: See [Comeonin Bcrypt does not support the 2y prefix?](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/issues/103) for the (directly unsupported) `2y` format workaround.

Comment: Does bcrypt stores it's issuer in the key? cause jwt does and then it would never match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @NicNilov mentioned, Comeonin does not support the `2y` prefix (which was created to work around a bug in a php implementation). It happens that `2y` is compatible with the `2b` variant so simply replacing the prefix will allow hashes to be verified.

[Example:](https://github.com/riverrun/comeonin/issues/103#issuecomment-366147074)

```
Comeonin.Bcrypt.checkpw(password, fix_prefix(password_hash))

defp fix_prefix("$2y" <> rest), do: "$2b" <> rest
defp fix_prefix(password_hash), do: password_hash
```